# JMeter gets stuck in load test

Tags: performance, jmeter

I'm new in performance testing and had already tried different tools for the job. When using JMeter, the generated report looks like these:

[image]

As you can see, JMeter gets stuck and then continues. I thought it was because of the Heap memory, but adding more memory did't resolve the problem.

Someone has an idea of what is happening here?

**UPDATE:**

The following image shows the metrics collected by PerfMon plugin:

[image]

And this one from JVisualVM:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think JMeter gets "stuck", what I see is throughput coming down from 1000 requests per second to ~200 requests per second.

Also these "jumps" from 0 to 1800 look very suspicious, if you load pattern doesn't assume this behaviour - you should also treat it as the issue.

Normally if you don't do any [spike testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing#Spike_testing) throughput should increase during ramp-up phase, decrease during ramp-down phase and remain the same for the duration of the test.

So I would recommend inspecting:

- application under test logs
- baseline OS health metrics on JMeter and application under test sides (CPU, RAM, Network, Disk, swap usage, etc.) - these can be collected using [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test) which in its turn can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)
- JMeter JVM specific metrics (Heap usage, GC activities, threads, etc.) - these can be collected using aforementioned JMeter PerfMon Plugin or other monitoring tool like [JVisualVM](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/index.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Dmitri T! I’m aware of the different types of performance testing (load, stress, spike), but the tests consists in hitting a server inside a Docker container. Jmeter is configured to create 10 users (threads), Ramp-up in 1 second and repeat that for 3000 times (the idea in this test is to get to know the limits of the server, how many req/sec can handle).
As you can see, there is not problem with JMeter with memory size and CPU, but what calls my attention is the Network IO...